# Consulta LINQ operador %

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

¿Que significa %2?

```
 string[] names = {"Geraldine", "Julieth", "Tatiana", "Maribel", "Susana", "Mónica"};
var Query = from x in names
        where (x.Length) > 5 && (((x.Length)%2)!=0)
        select x;
Query.Dump();
```

Comment: La respuesta de Luiggi es correcta. Por cierto no son necesarios tantos paréntesis en el where, simplemente podría ser así: `where x.Length > 5 && x.Length %2 != 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este caso, `%` es el [operador módulo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx). Para el código que presentas, la condición

```
(((x.Length)%2)!=0)
```

Significa que la longitud de x debe ser impar.